# OpenCl equivalent of finding Consecutive indices in CUDA

Tags: cuda, opencl, cuda.net, opencl.net

In CUDA to cover multiple blocks, and thus incerase the range of indices for arrays we do some thing like this:

Host side Code:

```
 dim3 dimgrid(9,1)// total 9 blocks will be launched    
 dim3 dimBlock(16,1)// each block is having 16 threads  // total no. of threads in  
                   //   the grid is thus 16 x9= 144.
```

Device side code

```
 ...
 ...     
 idx=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;// idx will range from 0 to 143 
 a[idx]=a[idx]*a[idx];
 ...
 ...
```

What is the equivalent in OpenCL for acheiving the above case ?

Comment: you may want to change the device side code. idx will range from 0 to 11 with the configuration you launched. you may want to do idx = (blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x)  * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; for it to have range between 0 and 143.

Comment: Ooops that was by mnistake... edited block dim, to one dim

Comment: So I did it this way:  

Host side: 

    localWorkSize[0]= 16;
    globalWorkSize[0] = 9*16;
  


Device Side: 

    
    int i= get_global_id(0) 
    a[idx]=a[idx]*a[idx];   
    ...   
    ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the host, when you enqueue your kernel using `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`, you have to specify the global and local work size. For instance:

```
size_t global_work_size[1] = { 144 }; // 16 * 9 == 144
size_t local_work_size[1] = { 16 };
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmd_queue, kernel, 1, NULL,
                       global_work_size, local_work_size,
                       0, NULL, NULL);
```

In your kernel, use:

```
size_t get_global_size(uint dim);
size_t get_global_id(uint dim);
size_t get_local_size(uint dim);
size_t get_local_id(uint dim);
```

to retrieve the global and local work sizes and indices respectively, where `dim` is `0` for `x`, `1` for `y` and `2` for `z`.

The equivalent of your `idx` will thus be simply `size_t idx = get_global_id(0);`

See the [OpenCL Reference Pages](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/).

Answer (score 1):

Equivalences between CUDA and OpenCL are:

```
blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x = get_global_id(0)

LocalSize = blockDim.x

GlobalSize = blockDim.x * gridDim.x
```